# Convert query string dictionary (or associative array) to dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, query-string

I'm trying to accept a query string of the form

```
?param[key1]=value1&param[key2]=value2
```

and convert it into a Dictionary in C# MVC 4. This is trivial to do in PHP, but I haven't been able to find any method of reproducing this in C#.

I know I can take an array via

```
?param=value1&param=value2
```

but that leaves issues of ordering and isn't nearly as useful for my purposes.

In the hopes that this isn't a limitation of the framework, how might I implement a dictionary-style conversion in C#?

> To clarify: I'm not looking to convert a query string into an NVC, but rather to convert query string parameters into their own NVCs. This is *NOT* as simple as ParseQueryString() or the Request.QueryString object.

Comment: The linked "duplicate" answer doesn't properly answer this question, wish I could vote to re-open it, but this is still an issue for me in 2019 that I haven't found an elegant solution for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here I fixed some code that will work for you, defo not the best solutioin but it should work.

```
   string basestring = "?param[key1]=value1&param[key2]=value2";
        string newstring = basestring.Replace("?", "").Replace("param[", "").Replace("]", "");
        var array = newstring.Split('&');
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var onestring in array)
        {
            var splitedstr = onestring.Split('=');
            dictionary.Add(splitedstr[0],splitedstr[1]);
        }
```

Comment: This is the solution I came to as well, but it feels rather inelegant. I was hoping there might be some automatic parsing similar to MVC's management of query strings like `?param=value1&param=value2`

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use the `Request.QueryString` collection that Asp.Net provides for you?  Since you are using MVC, it will be on your controllers `ControllerContext` property (located on that object's `HttpContext` property).

Comment: If it's MVC they should be parameters to the action method.

Comment: @asawyer  Thats a good point, but it is good to know where you can find it say if you are creating a custom model binder, you will be able to get it off the `ControllerContext`.

Comment: The Request.QueryString NVC contains keys that would be accessed like qs["param[key1]"] whereas I'm looking to access them as qs["param"]["key1"], although ideally I'd like to simply access param["key1"] directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this

```
    public ActionResult SubmitFormWithFormCollection(FormCollection parameters)
    {
        foreach (string param in parameters)
        {
            ViewData[param] = parameters[param];
        }

        return View();
    }
```